# Syntax for returning multi-dimensional array by reference in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, return

I've been killing myself trying to figure out the syntax for returning a 2 dimensional array by reference in C++, but I've been getting some very weird errors. I've also searched a lot online, but I couldn't find the syntax for returning by reference specifically. Could any of you please help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Some good soul helped me out, I would never have guessed it was this:

```
Type (&Scope::GetArray())[X][Y]
```